# Can't remove bottom "margin" on Primefaces SelectOneMenu

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

In the [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf), a SelectOneMenu is placed within a table cell.  Here's the layout of the containing cell:

[image]

But, if I replicate the Showcase HTML structure and include its default.css, the layout I get looks like this:

[image]

Somehow they differ by **~3px!**

This is annoying because I'm creating a form with input elements.  Whenever I use SelectOneMenus, the grid row is slightly too large:

[image]

Any idea of how to remove this bottom "margin"?  The developer tools in Chrome/FF/IE aren't revealing the root cause...

Comment: Without seeing your HTML + CSS output it is difficult for anyone to answer this question. Your primefaces code is probably not relevant.

Comment: I don't have custom CSS/HTML.  I'm simply putting a vanilla SelectOneMenu on my page.  Do you want to see the CSS and HTML that JSF/Primefaces generates?  My comment about duplicating the Showcase example was to simply prove that their CSS isn't fixing the problem (yet, it somehow doesn't exist).  If I knew of some other CSS/technique that they are using, I can figure out the issue myself.

Comment: This is a client-side problem, therefore you need to adjust the generated CSS.

Comment: @Pakman Have you solved this problem? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @Jin Kwon Added the answer...I think

Comment: @Pakman And I up-ed your answer.

Comment: @Jin Kwon Thanks for confirming (and the upvote)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:block` to your css for the SelectOneMenu:

```
.ui-selectonemenu {
    display: block;
}
```